# How to write additional data to a table when using CakePHP 2.x Tree Behaviour

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.0

I'm working with a CakePHP 2.x application and using the Tree Behaviour which comes with it - https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

My table is called `navigations` and has the following schema which is provided in the docs:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE navigations;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lft       | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rght      | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     |         |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

My Model, `Navigation.php` is configured to use the Tree behaviour:

```
class Navigation extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Tree');
}
```

I can write data into my table as per the documentation, e.g.

```
$data['Navigation']['parent_id'] = 3;
$data['Navigation']['name'] = 'United Kingdom';
$this->Navigation->save($data);
```

However... I have a requirement to store some additional data in the table.

If I add a field to my table, `jstree_data` of type `VARCHAR(255)`, I cannot write it to the table with the following:

```
$data['Navigation']['parent_id'] = 3;
$data['Navigation']['name'] = 'United Kingdom';
$data['Navigation']['jstree_data'] = 'foo'; // Attempt to write to 'jstree_data' field in database
$this->Navigation->save($data);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this? It seems that by using the Tree Behaviour (`public $actAs = array('Tree')` in the model) you lose the normal functionality of models and being able to save other data.

**Background info:**

Why am I trying to do this? I'm using jstree on a project. I need to delete all of the existing records before resaving the tree. However, because the `id` column is an `auto_increment` I need to store a reference for the "old ID" in `jstree_data` because that's what's present in the JSON data that comes from jstree. Based on this I can then look up the "new" ID (the auto increment value) and assign that with `$data['Navigation']['parent_id']` when resaving the new child elements.

Comment: assuming [this](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#modifying-data) did not worked, you can use [afterSave callback method](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave) to update the row

Comment: Clear your model (schema) cache (`tmp/cache/models`).